# AEM 6.5 rollout using Groovy script

Tags: aem

I'm trying to use Groovy to roll out a blueprint page to a specific live copy page. The following script works in AEM 6.5 but it rolls out to all the live copies. It ignores 'targets'.

How can I limit the rollout to the page specified in the target_path variable?

```
import com.day.cq.wcm.msm.api.RolloutManager;
import com.day.cq.wcm.msm.api.RolloutManager.RolloutParams;


source_path = '/content/mysite/en/about-us';
target_path = '/content/mysite/en_us/about-us';

resource = resourceResolver.getResource(source_path);

masterPage = resource.adaptTo(Page.class);

rolloutParms = RolloutParams.newInstance();

rolloutParms.master = masterPage;
rolloutParms.targets= target_path;
rolloutParms.isDeep = false;
rolloutParms.reset= false;

def rolloutManager = getService('com.day.cq.wcm.msm.api.RolloutManager');
rolloutManager.rollout(rolloutParms);
```

Comment: May be you are not setting targets correctly. Can you try updating ```rolloutParms.targets= [target_path];``` ?

Comment: thanks @phemanthkumar28.    Putting target_path in brackets solved the issue.  
target_path = ['/content/mysite/en_us/about-us'];

Comment: Glad it worked.

Answer (score 1):

Putting target_path in brackets solved the issue. target_path = ['/content/mysite/en_us/about-us']